# Passing URL parameters in code behind

Tags: asp.net

I need to pass parameters contains in the URL, when the user clicks a link.

`<li><a href='<%# GetURLPath() %>'><font color="red">User link</font></a></li>`

When my url looks like this,

```
http://localhost:1241/Home.aspx?userid=123&username=prosper
```

My first try:

```
protected string GetURLPath()
 {
   return "/Request.aspx?UserID=" + Request.QueryString["userid"] + "&UserName=" + Request.QueryString["username"];
 }
```

My second try,

```
string userid;
string username;

userid = (string)(Session["userid"]);
username = (string)(Session["userid"]);

return "Request.aspx?UserID=" + userid + "&UserName=" + username;
```

The problem I'm having is, the intended page Request.apsx doesn't get loaded. On a side note, when I handled this issue in designer.cs the parameters won't get passed to the Request.apsx.

Thanks!

Comment: And your question is.......?

Comment: Passing `username` or `password` as such (without any encryption) in query string is not a good practice. so please avoid such method and try to keep username/ password in session or cookies

Comment: @PoornimaN I've asked my senior developer the exact question. I've been told told that it displayed only for a fraction of a second and the url get redirected.

Comment: @Prosper - That sounds like a fairly lax attitued for a senior dev,   Even if it's redirected there are easy ways (and tools) to catch that URL before it's  redirected.

Comment: @Tim I am not comfortable with that too. I'll try to convince my team on this. Thanks all for help and advise. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change <%# GetURLPath() %> to <%= GetURLPath() %>.
For example,

```
<li><a href='<%= GetURLPath() %>'><font color="red">User link</font></a></li>
```

Comment: Worked with this code. return "Request.aspx?UserID=" + userid + "&UserName=" + username; Thanks